# For my nested type maven project i am getting a warning to give different groupid for different modules. ie. for services and webapps modules

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIB0I.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVd2g.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZaMo.jpg)I have given the same group id for different modules and have got some warnings. Is it okay to give different modules same group-id i.e like for modules services and web-apps? is it compulsory to give different groupid for different modules or same groupid, what is the best way to give groupid for different modules because at the end maybe just not compulsory and we may keep it under same?

Comment: What kind of warning do you get? Please post it here ? Furthermore an example project would really help...

Comment: Added project structure image. Can you tell me if I can give the same groupid for sub-projects of these? As actually these projects are under two folders i.e services and webapps ideally there should be two groupids, is it so?